Custome shape bottom navigation bar
How do i make this shape in Jetpack Compose?

The middle seems like a floating button but I want to treat it as part of the bottom navigation since it is also a navigation (the main one to be exact) and has that chosen white line under it.
I did not get much further just with the basic:
@Composable
fun myAppBottomNavigationBar(
    bottomNavigationListItem: ImmutableList<myAppBottomNavigation>,
    selected: myAppBottomNavigation,
    showBadge: ImmutableList<myAppBottomNavigation>,
    onBottomNavigationItemClicked: (myAppBottomNavigation) -> Unit,
) {
    BottomAppBar(
        containerColor = PrimaryColor,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                    topStart = 15.dp,
                    topEnd = 15.dp
                ),
            )
    ) {
        bottomNavigationListItem.forEach { myAppBottomNavigation ->
            when (myAppBottomNavigation) {
                CHAT -> NavigationBarItem(
                    selected = selected == myAppBottomNavigation,
                    icon = {
                        myAppBottomNavigationItem(
                            iconImage = MessageBottomNavigation,
                            showBadge = myAppBottomNavigation in showBadge
                        )
                    },
                    onClick = {
                        onBottomNavigationItemClicked(myAppBottomNavigation)
                    }
                )

                HISTORY -> {
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        selected = selected == myAppBottomNavigation,
                        icon = {
                            myAppBottomNavigationItem(
                                iconImage = HistoryBottomNavigation,
                                showBadge = myAppBottomNavigation in showBadge
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            onBottomNavigationItemClicked(myAppBottomNavigation)
                        }
                    )
                }

                SWIPE -> {
                    FloatingActionButton(
                        onClick = {

                        },
                        shape = CircleShape
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = SwipeBottomNavigation,
                            contentDescription = "",
                            tint = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                }

                PREMIUM -> {
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        selected = selected == myAppBottomNavigation,
                        icon = {
                            myAppBottomNavigationItem(
                                iconImage = DiamondBottomNavigation,
                                showBadge = myAppBottomNavigation in showBadge
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            onBottomNavigationItemClicked(myAppBottomNavigation)
                        }
                    )
                }

                PROFILE -> {
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        selected = selected == myAppBottomNavigation,
                        icon = {
                            myAppBottomNavigationItem(
                                iconImage = UserBottomNavigation,
                                showBadge = myAppBottomNavigation in showBadge
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            onBottomNavigationItemClicked(myAppBottomNavigation)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And this is how it looks:

Ignore the colors. How do I achieve the design in the middle in M3?

https://medium.com/@mahbooberezaee68/curved-cut-out-bottom-navigation-in-jetpack-compose-with-floatingactionbutton-fab-af7c938ba8c1 start with this. use bezeir curves and make your own shape
